# Create custom pagination buttons with custom style in grails

Tags: grails, pagination

How could I create custom buttons for pagination in grails application? I need a simple next and previous buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look in the [Twitter Bootstrap TagLib](https://github.com/groovydev/twitter-bootstrap-grails-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/taglib/org/groovydev/TwitterBootstrapTagLib.groovy), they modified the pagination to apply the bootstrap layout.